# How to fix the issue of Invalid viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have developed one web application in ASP.NET(Framework 4) with C# and deployed on one external server. As I checked server's log, the **Invalid ViewState** exception logged periodically. To resolve this issue, I have tried many solutions but non of that worked for me. I don't want to set enableviewstatemac property to false in web.config for security reason. (May be setting this to false will resolve the issue.)

Getting this error even for the pages that contains very small amounts of controls.

**Error Description/Stacktrace:**

```
Application_Error | Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: [IP]
Port: 26824
Referer: [URL with parameter]
Path: /page.aspx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; SAMSUNG SM-G610F Build/M1AJQ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/7.4 Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
ViewState: 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...at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose)
```

**Try 1**: Used Machine key(key for .Net 4.0) generated by one online tool in config file.

Code:

```
<machineKey
validationKey='2EEA416CEFC6D6BE856ED57B97FB9CA7DFACE17C073125949A1D682C80A44BB2A
D887DDDC13DBFB0954F1000FEE5757E99693F222F8E28CAA2E6DAB8C4F99E0C'
decryptionKey='877478B2F33A74226ABEF55FDCC1A76E43F1BBEA6241A592'
validation='SHA1' />
<pages enableViewStateMac='true'/>
</system.web>
```

**Try 2**: Compressing the ViewState

As code is long, I have added link of the code here that I have tried.[Compressing the ViewState](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14733/ViewState-Compression)

**Try 3**: MaxPageStateFieldLength property of page in web.config.

In this way, in web.config file, it showing warning as MaxPageStateFieldLength attribute is not allowed.

Code:

```
  <system.web>
    <pages MaxPageStateFieldLength="20"/>
  </system.web>
```

**Try 4**: Place hidden fields for Encrypted Viewstate and Event validation on the top of the form

In this way, I have override the Render event of Page and write the code taken from this link: [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error/)

None of the above solutions worked for me. Please correct me if I have did any thing wrong in above ways. Please ask for any other inputs if more clarification is needed.

Currently I have provided one workaround. I have catched this specific exception in application's error event and redirect to same page that causing this issue. But I am not satisfied with this workaround as issue is still exist.

**Workaround**:

```
   void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        if (exception != null)
        {
            if (exception is System.Web.HttpException && exception.InnerException is System.Web.UI.ViewStateException)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                WriteLog("Application_Error", "Invalid viewstate | Redirect to: " + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLog("Application_Error", exception.InnerException.Message + "|" + exception.StackTrace + "|" + Request.RawUrl);
            }
        }
        // Clear the error from the server
        Server.ClearError();
    }
```

Comment: If you can, you should move to another technology like ASP.NET MVC, because ASP.NET WebForms is dead.

Comment: Yes, I welcome and accept your suggestion but it will take some more time for me to switch to other technology.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly not helpful.

Comment: My suggestion was based on two things really: (1) It seamed to me that your application is rather new/small and this might be a good option. (2) Most people using WebForms don't really understand what ViewState is and how it works. They think they do, but they mix it up with other things not related to it. Therefore problems with ViewState can get pretty tricky. I always suggest the following article in that case, maybe it can help you too: https://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Yes, I agree with your opinion as my application is new and small scale application and also I am newer to web application development.
I have gone through article you have shared but not even able to identify the reason of my problem.
The reason or cause of the issue may also helpful to me so that I can search accordingly towards the solution.

Comment: I haven't worked with WebForms for a long time now, so I can't really help you in debugging. But I remember having this error, when the user would use the browser's back/forward buttons to navigate to a WebForms page and then press one of the controls on it.